# XSLT sorting by multiple elements

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am quite a newbie in XSLT, and have to perform a transformation from XML to XML. Basically reformatting the file. The XML file bellow is the input, and is normally longer, but as it was irrelevant for the question, I only selected parts of the file. I am also obliged to use XSLT v1.0.

**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <transaction_date>01/11/2019</transaction_date>
        <customerID>31F9PCQD</customerID>
        <giftShop>2</giftShop>
        <transactionID>1ygOIpJ6Tf2HB72e</transactionID>
        <value currency="gbp">57.43</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <transaction_date>01/11/2019</transaction_date>
        <customerID>4FI1TAJW</customerID>
        <giftShop>1</giftShop>
        <transactionID>7Yog0IVnlVbOGIQX</transactionID>
        <value currency="gbp">54.12</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <transaction_date>01/11/2019</transaction_date>
        <customerID>9B237CBO</customerID>
        <giftShop>3</giftShop>
        <transactionID>DJs5rDV21qeIuKnb</transactionID>
        <value currency="gbp">10.09</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <transaction_date>01/11/2019</transaction_date>
        <customerID>FDCXOH0M</customerID>
        <giftShop>2</giftShop>
        <transactionID>2lZ75q0FrSpcREjs</transactionID>
        <value currency="gbp">49.49</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <transaction_date>01/11/2019</transaction_date>
        <customerID>9VDK67SH</customerID>
        <giftShop>3</giftShop>
        <transactionID>CwNGDKipz6ZAE0NZ</transactionID>
        <value currency="gbp">36.08</value>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <transaction_date>01/11/2019</transaction_date>
        <customerID>BQ0JG15U</customerID>
        <giftShop>1</giftShop>
        <transactionID>xiFZUFOv8J8zKqyU</transactionID>
        <value currency="gbp">19.76</value>
    </transaction>
```

What I'd like to do, is rearrange this file by Shops (so either shop 1 | 2 | 3), and then by dates. The thing is, I really cannot find a way of doing it. I've tried to use the Muenchian grouping method, to avoid replicates of shops and dates, but I cannot manage to select the correct data and put it in the correct shop.

**The output xml should have the following structure:**

```
<Transactions>
    <Shop id="1">
        <Date>
            <Transaction>
                Transaction and customer details...
            </Transaction>
        </Date>
        <Date>
            <Transaction>
                Transaction and customer details...
            </Transaction>
        </Date>
        ...
    </Shop>

    <Shop id="2">
        <Date>
            <Transaction>
                Transaction and customer details...
            </Transaction>
        </Date>
        <Date>
            <Transaction>
                Transaction and customer details...
            </Transaction>
        </Date>
        ...
    </Shop>

    <Shop id="3">
    <Date>
            <Transaction>
                Transaction and customer details...
            </Transaction>
        </Date>
        ...
    </Shop>
</Transactions>
```

I'm not sure my question is well formulated or clear, but any guidelines would be much appreciated. **Thank you in advance for your time.**

Comment: See an example of subgrouping here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525214/3016153. If you cannot make it work, post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: cheers ! My recent attempt were not presentable at all so I thought it was irrelevant :)), as I said, I only asked for guidelines, I know every one has its own stuff to do. Thanks again !