# Grouping and skip duplicates in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates, grouping

I'm trying to produce an XML from the original one that will be grouping the same `Item/@Id` while skipping the child duplicates within `item`

**Source XML:**

```
<products>
    <item id="1">
        <content desc="laptop"/>
        <content desc="charger"/>
    </item>
    <item id="1">
        <content desc="laptop"/>
        <content desc="charger"/>
        <content desc="mouse"/>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <content desc="laptop"/>
        <content desc="charger"/>
    </item>        
</products>
```

I've been checking several posts with similar question, but I'm stuck with below XSLT 1.0 code I'm trying my own:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="itemKey" match="item" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="products">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('itemKey', @id)[1])]">
            <product>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>                
                </id>
                <content>
                     <xsl:for-each select="content">
                        <desc>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@desc"/>
                        </desc>                         
                     </xsl:for-each>    
                </content>
            </product>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From the source XML, there are in total 2 item ids (1 and 2) and the group with `item id="1"` has `laptop` and `charger` repeated in both, so those should appear only once, and `mouse` will complete that group. The expected output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <product>
      <id>1</id>
      <detail>
          <item>laptop</item>
          <item>charger</item>
          <item>mouse</item>
      </detail>
   </product>
   <product>
      <id>2</id>
      <detail>
          <item>laptop</item>
          <item>charger</item>
      </detail>
   </product>
</output>
```

I was reading that I probably have to first do a group by `item/@id` and then for each group do another group by `content/@desc` but not sure how to accomplish that. Can you please let me know what changes do I need to do to in my XSLT in order to achieve the expected result? Solution is expected in XSLT 1.0, but I'd also consider XSLT 2.0.

Using **XSLT 2.0** again I'm not sure how to capture the unique `content` for each group

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">    
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="@id">
            <product>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> 
                </id>
                <content>
                                       
                </content>
            </product>            
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to do sub-grouping within each group. See if you can adapt the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525214/3016153

Comment: P.S. If you can use XSLT 2.0, why would you bother with Muenchian grouping??

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes that post I was also checking but unfortunately, I wasn't able to make it work in my case. I was doing Muenchian grouping because I was told to use XSLT 1.0, but at this point I will also consider XSLT 2.0. Please see my post for the XSLT 2.0 approach.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adaption of [the answer I linked to earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525214/3016153) is straightforward; I don't see why you had a problem with it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="content" match="content" use="concat(@desc, '|', ../@id)" />

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <output>
        <!-- a group for each unique item id -->
        <xsl:for-each select="item[count(. | key('item', @id)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
            <product>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>                
                </id>
                <detail>
                    <!-- for each unique content in this group -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('item', @id)/content[count(. | key('content', concat(@desc, '|', $id))[1]) = 1]">
                        <item>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@desc"/>
                        </item>       
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </detail>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

As also mentioned in the comments, doing this in **XSLT 2.0** is much easier:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
    <output>
        <!-- a group for each unique item id -->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="@id">
            <product>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>                
                </id>
                <detail>
                    <!-- for each unique content in this group -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(current-group()/content/@desc)">
                        <item>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </item>       
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </detail>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```