XSLT sorting unique items
I need to sort some XML and get the HTML.
My XML:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<global>
    <item university="Harvard" staff="Matt Dillon" course="American History"/>
    <item university="Harvard" staff="Matt Dillon" course="Philosophy"/>
    <item university="Harvard" staff="Matt Dillon" course="Social Psychology"/>
    <item university="Harvard" staff="Simon Pegg" course="Government"/>
    <item university="Harvard" staff="Simon Pegg" course="Sociobiology"/>
    <item university="Harvard" staff="Christian Bale" course="Astronomy"/>
    <item university="Harvard" staff="Christian Bale" course="Economics"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Jean Reno" course="Chemistry"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Jean Reno" course="Natural Sciences"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Jean Reno" course="Atmospheric Chemistry"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Simon Pegg" course="Social Psychology"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Simon Pegg" course="Political Philosophy"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Adrien Brody" course="Mathematics"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Adrien Brody" course="Economics"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Adrien Brody" course="Computer Science"/>
    <item university="Stanford" staff="Adrien Brody" course="Astrophysics"/>
</global>

I created an XSLT where I applied the Munch sorting twice:
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="key_univ" match="/global/item" use="@university"/> 
    <xsl:key name="key_staff" match="/global/item" use="@staff"/>
    <xsl:template match="global">
          <html>               
            <body>
                <ul>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:variable name="key1" select="key('key_univ',@university)"/> 
  
    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=generate-id($key1)">
        <li><h3><xsl:value-of select="@university"/></h3></li>
          <p>Count: <xsl:value-of select="count($key1[@course])"/></p>
          <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="$key1">
              <xsl:variable name="key2" select="key('key_staff',@staff)"/>
              <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=generate-id($key2)">
                  <li><h4><xsl:value-of select="@staff"/></h4></li>
                 <p>Count: <xsl:value-of select="count($key2[@course])"/></p>
                  <ul>
                       <xsl:for-each select="$key2">
                         <li><xsl:value-of select="@course"/></li>
                       </xsl:for-each>
                  </ul>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
The code works and the result is good. But I don't understand why, when sorting, Simon Pegg ends up at Harvard University twice, although he should appear at Harvard once and Stanford once.
I think we need to register a local variable somewhere. But nothing comes to mind. Please help me solve this problem.

Your stylesheet does NOT perform any sorting, so it is hard to understand what you're talking about. Seeing the expected result would also help. --- I suspect you are looking for a solution similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525214/17153010.

The script is working correctly. I mean, the teacher who belongs to Stanford is displayed at Oxford. https://imgbly.com/ib/z1bBXY3q3G

I am afraid that's not making any sense.

Are you restricted to XSLT 1? In XSLT 2 and later a nested xsl:for-each-group makes such things much easier. But for XSLT 1 I think the link posted in the first comment should help you to change one of your keys and the key function calls.

Yes, I try to solve this task in XSLT 1.

Here is how nested grouping in XSLT 2 or later makes this easy:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="global">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>nested grouping example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="@university">
            <li><h3><xsl:value-of select="@university"/></h3></li>
            <p>Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></p>
            <ul>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@staff">
                <li><h4><xsl:value-of select="@staff"/></h4></li>
                <p>Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/></p>
                <ul>
                   <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                     <li><xsl:value-of select="@course"/></li>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
              </xsl:for-each-group>
            </ul>            
          </xsl:for-each-group>          
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

And with two level keys and Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1 you can do
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="key_univ" match="/global/item" use="@university"/> 
    <xsl:key name="key_staff" match="/global/item" use="concat(@university, '|', @staff)"/>
    <xsl:template match="global">
          <html>               
            <body>
                <ul>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key_univ', @university)[1])]"/>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <li><h3><xsl:value-of select="@university"/></h3></li>
  <p>Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(key('key_univ', @university))"/></p>
  <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('key_univ', @university)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key_staff', concat(@university, '|', @staff))[1])]">
      <li><h4><xsl:value-of select="@staff"/></h4></li>
      <p>Count: <xsl:value-of select="count(key('key_staff', concat(@university, '|', @staff)))"/></p>
      <ul>
         <xsl:for-each select="key('key_staff', concat(@university, '|', @staff))">
           <li><xsl:value-of select="@course"/></li>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

